# android admob on canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I am trying to add an admob to my game,
I am using a surfaceview for drawing my canvas,
So this is the main layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a151e48ea219c98"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the main activity

```
    MykSurface ourSurfaceView;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ourSurfaceView =  (MySurface) findViewById(R.id.surface);
}
```

And this is the class where I run my drawing canvas on the surface

```
public class MySurface extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
            .....
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            while (isRunning) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(bg, 0, 0, null);
        }
            .....
}
```

The problem is I cann't "connect" ourSurfaceView with the surfaceview on the layout to use it for drawing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never instantiating MySurface.

Either modify activity_main.xml to explicitly instantiate it:

```
<com.yourcompany.MySurface
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

or programatically add it in onCreate of your main Activity.

Note also that specifying the layout_width and height of the SurfaceView to match_parent will mean that the AdView will never have any room. Either specify the AdView first and mark the SurfaceView as being below the AdViuew OR use a LinearLayout instead of a RelativeLayout and use layout_weight=1 for the SurfaceView to let it expand to fill the unused space.